# Embed Foursquare map on site and mark some places

Tags: html, maps, foursquare

I need to embed Foursquare map of certain city (with marked places) on site and mark some places by given coordinates.
Can you help me? I can't find needed topic on Foursquare Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [search venues API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) with the `near` parameter for every city you want to get the places you want.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I know the coordinates, so I use it with ll parameter.